# Pcie 1.1 device is not detected on a pcie gen 3 slot

Tags: linux-device-driver, pci-e

My PC is running in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel version 3.11.0-23.

The link below is my PC model: http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/HP_Pavilion_500_232d

I inserted a x4 pcie 1.1 device on the x16 PCIE 3.0 slot. When I do lspci, my device is not shown in the list.

I tested my device on other PC with Gen 2.0 slot and it is detected.

Is there a way for my device to be detected?

Thanks in advance!

Regards, Fed

Answer (score 0):

Is the device bus powered? Do you have a way to tell if it is powered ?(led?)

Is the device FPGA based ? If yes it might not respect the amount of time a device must be ready to answer to the first transaction (50ms after power up I believe).

Comment: Hi Claudio, Yes it is powered. There is a power led that is on. And yes it is FPGA based.

Comment: Hi Fedemar, you can rule out FPGA configuration time (which delays the time of first response) by doing a warm reboot and see if the device enumerates. Alternatively you may need to use a logic analyzer (in FPGA) to see what is happening at enumeration (the PCIe IP should have some status registers that you can probe)